# Inherited Property of Model is always returning Null Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view which displays a radiobutton list on left side of the page and it also loads a partialview on right side of the page which consist of various filters to be selected before displaying a report in a popup window.

The problem is that the property named 'ReportName' always return a Null value when submit button is pressed instead of the returning a string value of selected Radiobutton Other properties such as Branchcode, PeriodFrom, PeriodTo return correctly.

what should i do to get proper string value such as AppointmentSummary, SplcodeRegSummary, or SplcodeReg when its radiobutton is selected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**MODEL:**

```
public class ReportModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Report!")]
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
}

public class ReportFilters :ReportModel         //inherited 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please select Branch name!")]
    public int BranchCode { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify 'Period from' date!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PeriodFrom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify 'Period to' date!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PeriodTo { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult MIS1()
{
    ViewBag.Branch = (from c in BranchList().AsEnumerable()
                      orderby c["BranchName"]
                      select new { BranchCode = c["BranchCode"], BranchName = c["BranchName"] }).ToList();

    return PartialView();
}


public ActionResult MISPopup(ReportFilters rf)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(rf);
    }
    return View();
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
<td>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReportName, "AppointmentSummary", new { id = "AppointmentSummary" })
    @Html.Label("AppointmentSummary", "Appointment Summary")<br />

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReportName, "SplcodeRegSummary", new { id = "SplcodeRegSummary" })
    @Html.Label("SplcodeRegSummary", "Special codewise Registration summary")<br />

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ReportName, "SplcodeReg", new { id = "SplcodeReg" })
    @Html.Label("SplcodeReg", "Special codewise Registrations")<br />
</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ReportFilters.cshtml")
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

**PARTIAL VIEW:**

```
@model MVCProject.Models.ReportFilters
@using (Html.BeginForm("MISPopup", "MIS", FormMethod.Get, new { target = "_blank" }))
{ 
<div >
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportName)
                @Html.Label("ClinicBranch", "Clinic Branch")
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                @try
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BranchCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.Branch, "BranchCode", "BranchName"), "--Select Branch--")
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("Branch", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Branch--")
                }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchCode)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("FromDate", "From date")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PeriodFrom)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PeriodFrom)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("ToDate", "To date")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PeriodTo)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PeriodTo)
            </td>
        <tr><td colspan="4"><br /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="image" id="submit" value="View"  src="~/Images/View.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You radio button group is not inside the `<form>` tags so its value is not sent when the form is submitted. You need to move the radio buttons to inside the form (in the partial) and remove the hidden input for property `ReportName`.

If this is not possible you could consider handling the `click()` event of the radio buttons as using javascript/jquery to update the hidden input inside the form

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I shifted the Html.BeginForm from the partial view to the main view and it worked.